# Which database would be the best for a production Android app?

Tags: android, database

I am implementing an Android application but I can't make a final decision about which database will be the most suitable. You can think of my app as Instagram but there will not be photos or videos, there will be texts instead. There will only be images for profile pictures.

Users may insert data to database and make advanced search inside the app. So the database must be somewhere where anyone using the app can communicate. What is the best choice?

Comment: Try to Use firebase

Comment: Are you sure Firebase would be sufficient for such an app? Check this link out, he says why he wouldn't choose Firebase if it were a production app: https://github.com/mitchtabian/Android-Instagram-Clone/tree/cb5008eed6fd56db1ad0a768b4a289b5aeae99f6

Comment: You just dont know  what you are talking about , firebase has many cool features which can be just achieved in one line such us real time meassaging etc

Comment: Opinion questions are off topic here.  So are requests for libraries/software advice.  And even if it wasn't doubly off topic, you haven't begun to give us enough data about your use case to give you more than "name your favorite database".

Comment: @GabeSechan this is not as shallow as you approach. One would come up and say "MySQL is bla bla whereas Firebase is bla bla.... therefore it would be better to use bla bla.. ". This question is as straight and legit as giving a piece of code and asking how to make textview bold, if you know what I mean

Comment: @devNO such questions are off topic here. Nor did you give us anywhere bar the data needed to give you that type of an answer

Comment: @GabeSechan you could have simply said you don't know :)

Comment: @devNo Its not a matter of not knowing.  Its a matter of nowhere near a complete picture of your use case.  Are you online only or offline?  What rate of reads?  What rate of writes?  How complicated are your queries?  Do you need triggers?  Stored procedures?  Is your data structured or unstructured?  What latencies do you need?  Do you need immediate consistency or eventual?  That's a good list for a very vague guess-  even that list isn't enough to actually answer your question.  What you gave us is enough to say "yeah, use a db"

Answer (score 0):

Not everything you read on the internet is always true. There are MANY services out there for you to use. Parse-Server, Firebase, AWS, MySQL, PHP...etc etc etc.

I, for one, am using Parse-Server. Why? It's simple. I make my own calls for statistics that will get stored in mongo. If I was to do it over again, I would use Firebase for it instead. Why? Google is king.

Now, Parse-Server and Firebase for example claim they are secure, and I haven't done much testing to see if I was able to crack into it. Perhaps someone can comment on this. Parse-Server is stored locally on my Mac, and as long as your keys stay secured, the app is secured. The db (which is stored on mongo) is secured. You can store images, text, users, and just about ANYTHING on mongo which again, is similar to Firebase.

If you want to best for production, I don't think you need to worry about Firebase, Parse-Server, AWS, etc, you need to worry about security. If it's hard to crack then that service might be the way to go.

Sure, maybe storing images separate from the text would be good, but again, if Parse-Server is secured, then I'm happy to use it for my needs.

edit: typo(s)